# Django error, coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.timedelta found

Tags: python, django, datetime, unicode

Here is the code where the error occurs:

```
date_arrive = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.session.get('arrival'), '%m/%d/%Y'),\
date_depart = date_arrive + datetime.timedelta(days=request.session.get('nights')))).save()
```

And everytime Django reaches this view, it throws the error:

```
Exception Value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.timedelta found
```

Here arrival is a valid datetime object and nights is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id suggest you include full listing of function call.

Seems that you try concatenating unicode and datatime object, that is not possible. You have to convert date_arrive to datetime or "datetime.timedelta(days=request.session.get('nights')" to unicode evidently, depending on type your function needs as date_depart argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this problem by making sure non-unicode/non-strings like integers and datetime objects are surrounded with a str(your_date_object_here).

When I encountered this error in Django I was able to fix it with both the following:

```
def __str__(self): 
    return str(self.datetimeobject) + " other string return info"
```

and

```
def __str__(self):
    return unicode(self.datetimeobject) + " other string return info"
```